# how do i include a static block in the footer only on homepage

Tags: layout, static-block, magento-1

This is my xml

```
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_video">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_video</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

This example is working, but it put my html code from my static block before the footer. If change the `reference name="footer"`. It doesn't work at all. Why ? What should I change ?

Comment: Following the explanation by here: http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/add-a-static-block-into-footer-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

Need to add `before="footer"`  at layout code. Basically using `before,after` tag ***magento maps element at current layout***.

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_video"  before="footer">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_video</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want add this CMS block in footer block, you have to add it also in footer template:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block_video') ?>
```