# Calling a static block in footer for homepage only

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, static-block

I want to call a static block after my footer and I want it to appear only on my homepage. Here below is my xml code as referred to [This Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95352/how-do-i-include-a-static-block-in-the-footer-only-on-homepage). But, it is loading the content above the footer when used after and not coming at all when used before.

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="home_page_content"  before="footer">
          <action method="setBlockId"><home_page_content>home_page_content</home_page_content></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open Home Page to edit.
- In `Custom Layout Update XML` textarea, paste code like this:

`<reference name="before_body_end">
<block type="cms/block" name="home_page_content">
<action method="setBlockId">
<home_page_content>test</home_page_content>
</action>
</block>
</reference>`

Remember to change block id from test to your own block identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in `footer.phtml` file `(app\design\frontend\{your-package}\{your-theme}\template\page\html\footer.phtml)`

```
<?php if (Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();?> 
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: No, it is coming in all tha pages

Comment: have you added <?php if (Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?> ?

Comment: clear all cache and try again and above code is right